# Add the ability to mark chat messages as "On-topic" or "Off-topic"

Tags: feature-request, chat

From time to time, "regular" users in SO chat may inadvertently stray "off-topic" from the room's official subject matter. I am proposing a request to add the ability to mark a chat message "off-topic".

**How it would work**

A user enters the chat and, by default, they will only see chat messages that are "on-topic". These messages are all related to the room's subject.

They may ask their question, and receive help from users in the room without any "off-topic" messages obscuring the help.

If a user has something to say or share that is not related to the subject matter, they may click a checkbox near or around the submit button. This message may only be viewed by users that have checked a checkbox elsewhere in the room that says, "View off-topic messages". If a user has mistakenly forgotten to mark a message as "on-topic" or "off-topic", they may change the status within the window of time set for the edit ability.

If the user has opted-in to viewing "off-topic" messages, both sets of messages will be viewable in the chat feed. The messages could have a darker background if they are "on-topic" so that they stand out more than the "off-topic" messages.

An ability could be granted to ROs to mark messages as "on-topic" or "off-topic" freely.

Comment: Wouldn't a message from an RO telling them to get back on track work just fine here? Chat messages aren't a main part of the site, and moderating should only be for extreme cases such as rudeness, hostileness, etc.

Comment: ok. It's hungarian, and it's a forum, but check the gray content of 2nd post. It's not unimplementable. And IMHO it would be useful: https://prohardver.hu/tema/dell_notebookok/hsz_1-50.html

Answer (score 15):

This seems like introducing unnecessary noise/distraction into a chat room. Room Owners already have several options they can use to combat off-topic messages.

- ignore the user posting off-topic messages (even non-Room Owners can do this) or hide their posts (I believe the difference is that one will ignore everywhere, the other will only ignore in the current room, but I'm not positive)
- warn, and then kick, the user for posting off-topic messages if they are really that problematic
- change access to the room so that only certain users can post messages
- move off-topic messages to one of several 'trash can' rooms
- **simply ask users posting off-topic messages to stop if the need for on-topic discussion arises**

Comment: [But even the chat FAQ doesn't forbid off-topic conversation.](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#about) Users are going to stray from subject matter from time-to-time, as most of the people in that particular room are like-minded people.

Comment: @Kramb So if the chat FAQ doesn't forbid off-topic conversation, what makes you expect they will implement a feature that hides off-topic conversation by default?

Comment: To assist users requesting help. If a user asks for help in a room that may currently be discussing something off-topic, than the question could potentially get buried. But if the question stood-out from the rest of the chat, than the users can see it more easily. This would also allow for users to not miss an answer to their question

Comment: @Kramb Any room owner should have the ability to create a new room for one-on-one conversations, if the user seeking help is below 100 reputation. I can't imagine any popular chatroom where excessive chitchat is a problem giving Room Owner powers to someone below 100 rep. But again, the RO asking everyone to pipe down or the user seeking help ignoring all the chatters both already exist as options to solve this problem. I don't see this feature being implemented.

Comment: This would just make the link-dumping worse.  All those posters with bad questions, (most of them), would add a 'dump on-topic link to chatroom' as a normal activity when posting their questions :(